# SSIS Lookup Component -- identify failed rows / send to trace output?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

**Environment:** SQL Server 2008 R2 with SSIS and SSAS.

**Short question:** Is there anyway to get SSIS to send the data row from a failed lookup to a trace event?

**Long question:** I'm pulling together a number of SSIS packages that do a number of transformations on data from tables that have up to a couple of million rows in them. The ultimate destination is an SSAS cube. All lookups should suceed -- failure indicates that a data quality issue has seeped in, so failing the entire ETL on a failed lookup is correct.

However there doesn't seem to be any easy way to get the SSIS Lookup component to report on which row failed when it logs "Row yieled no match during lookup" to the trace log. I'm looking to see if there's anything I can do to actually catch the failed row and get the row data logged in the trace at the same time.

At the moment, I'm having to resort to feeding non-matching rows to a CSV file for analysis, but this means the takeon then continues processing, which I don't want. In addition, hooking a file onto every lookup component means managing a large number of extra files (Which also need their associated connection managers configuring). I could, in theory, manage a single file if I fed all outputs into a Union transform, but when I'm dealing with packages that have up to 10-15 Lookup transforms, this gets messy very quickly.

I'm wondering if there's any way I can hook into the OnError event to get this data, but if there is, it's non-obvious.

Any other ideas welcome. I can't believe I'm the only one that's wondering how to do this, but my stackoverflow-fu and google-fu has abandoned me and I can't (oddly enough) find anything on this...

Cheers!

Comment: Are you meaning a SQL trace, or the DTS error log/table?

Comment: So you want your 'takeon' to stop processing after the first failed lookup?  Or do you want it to show all of the failed lookups?  It could be time consuming if you fail on the first error and have several data problems in the feed.

Comment: @Sam - either. Ultimately, can I trace the problematic line without having to add extr data flow elements to the config. To a log file/table would be best as then it can be viewed historically, but in profiler's fine as well tbh.

Comment: Also happy for it to stop dead on the first failure providing it tells me what that failure was. Generally I'm finding it's a code that's not come over right, so fixing it for a single failed row will fix it for all rows that would otherwise fail.

Comment: Might be worth taking a look at this article. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345163(v=sql.105).aspx - the gist seems to be the redirected row (if setup that way) provides an error code & description and this article expands on how to expand that error output.  The mechanics of this look to be a useful clue on how you might create the sort of output you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Could you redirect those rows into a table and put a 'source package' column in there to make querying them or making remedy reports simple?

Also, just an idea, but perhaps you could redirect all output to the 'trash output' on this [page](http://ssisctc.codeplex.com/).  Then you could continue logging lookup errors without moving data to the destination table.

Comment: The problem is I've got half a dozen transforms, the largest having about 20 different dataflows, the smallest having two dataflows, but each dataflow can have anything from two to a dozen lookup transforms. Redirecting errored rows to another table is going to get quite nasty quite quickly, so I'd rather just have some raw debug output with something telling me "Row yielded no match during lookup for value of {x}", or sending the row that failed reported somewhere. Ultimately, all I want to know is *what* was the value that failed in the lookup :-)